# No Such Method Exception on getting Nested property

Tags: java, exception, javabeans, nosuchmethod

I have defined an Employee object with the following properties

```
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

The Address object:

```
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String city;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

And have generated the getters and setters for the properties. When I do the following on the properties:

```
String value = BeanUtils.getNestedProperty(employee, "address.street");
```

I get a "No Such Method Exception" for address.street.

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'address.street' on class 'class com.test.xm.Employee'*

The fields id and name works fine.

Have double checked the getters and setters and it seems fine. What possibly could I be doing wrong here?

**Edit: Have updated the getters and setters.**

Comment: does your getter's and seters follow java bean conventions ?? show us your getters and setters

Comment: please make sure that seters are correct. can you post seter methods as well?

Comment: In other words, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR updated with getters and setters

Comment: please paste the exact error message

Answer (score 4):

Use `PropertyUtils` instead of `BeanUtils`.

```
   (String) PropertyUtilsBean.getInstance().getNestedProperty(employee, "address.street");
```

For me your example is working well too. So in your example, the only possible error is: `employee` isn't an instance of `Employee`.

Also why don't you post the Exception message? They contain very helpful information, for eg:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'address' on class 'class com.mycompany.dto.Address'
```